# データ構造（スタックやキューについて）

Tags: c++, データ構造

データ構造（スタックやキューについて）競技プログラミングの観点と実務という観点にてお聞きしたいことがあります。
C++等ではスタックやキューは標準ライブラリに入ってるとおもわれるのですが、このクラスを自分で拡張したりすることはあるのでしょうか？？

Comment: 「拡張」するか否かが質問のようですので、拡張について例示する等、もう少し具体的に説明してください。

Comment: そもそも `std::stack` は `template<class T, class Container = deque<T> > class stack { ... };` だから `Container` を差し替える＝拡張っぽい動作は最初から考慮済みなのですしね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> スタックやキューは標準ライブラリに入ってるとおもわれるのですが、このクラスを自分で拡張したりすることはあるのでしょうか？？

技術的には、拡張可能です。

C++標準ライブラリが提供する[`std::stack`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/stack/stack.html)(LIFOデータ構造)と[`std::queue`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/queue/queue.html)(FIFOデータ構造)は、要素値のデータ格納機構を外部に委ねるコンテナアダプタ(Container Adapter)となっています。このためクラステンプレート設計上は、プログラマによる拡張がある程度考慮されています。

両コンテナアダプタ共に、第2テンプレート引数にて具体的なデータ格納機構（コンテナ）を指定できます。省略時のデフォルトパラメータでは[`std::deque`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/deque/deque.html)コンテナが利用されます。

```cpp
// std::deque<int>を利用したスタック
std::stack<int> s0;
// std::deque<int>を利用したキュー
std::queue<int> q0;

// std::vector<int>を利用したスタック
std::stack<int, std::vector<int>> s1;
// std::list<int>を利用したキュー
std::queue<int, std::list<int>> q1;
```

また両コンテナアダプタ共に、その内部でデータ格納に利用するコンテナを保持しており、そのメンバ変数`c`をprotectedアクセスとして派生先クラスへと公開しています。つまり`std::stack`や`std::queue`クラスから継承した独自クラスを作成し、通常のスタック／キューにはない特別な操作を行うメンバ関数を追加することもできます。

Comment: デストラクタが非virtualなので、継承することは想定されていない、ということはないでしょうか？

Comment: 基底クラスのデストラクタが非virtualの場合、イディオムとしてはprivateクラス継承を用いれば安全に利用できます。virtualメンバ関数（デストラクタ）の存在はメモリ空間的・実行コスト的な追加オーバーヘッドが生じます。protectedメンバ変数は継承以外に使い道がありませんから、クラス設計としては継承が想定されているはずです。

Answer (score 0):

> C++等ではスタックやキューは標準ライブラリに入ってるとおもわれるのですが、このクラスを自分で拡張したりすることはあるのでしょうか？？

なにを聞きたいのかイマイチわかりませんが、あるかないかを聞かれれば、ある、ということになろうかと。